# Toggle UART (enable_uart=1) without rebooting

Tags: pi-zero-w, uart, config.txt

Which pins can can I manually toggle to enable or disable UART on a Raspberry Pi Zero or 3B+ without rebooting? As I understand, /boot/config.txt is parsed before Linux is started, but I don't mind getting my hands dirty with chip-level GPIO.

Typically a reboot is required after setting `enable_uart=1` in `/boot/config.txt`.

**Edit:** It seems like the `UARTEN` register can be toggled as per page 184 of the [BCM2835 spec](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2835/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf).

Comment: It's not possible to do that.